# expo auth session spotify get refresh token

Tags: react-native, express, axios, expo, spotify

I am trying to do spotify login via the expo-auth-session on my expo app
In the expo-auth-session doc,
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#spotify

I understand that the auth code flow gives me the authorization code in the response, and the implicit flow gives me the access token in the response. Neither flow gives me the aDoes anyone know how to get the refresh token?

I tried calling the refresh token endpoint using the authorization code that I got from the auth code flow, but it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You can get refresh token by curl

```
curl -d client_id={CLIENT_ID} \
-d client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET} \
-d grant_type=authorization_code \
-d code={CODE} \
-d redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI} \
https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

[image]

### Step 1 - create your application

Create your App in [Spotify Developer Dashboard](https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/applications)

Get `Client ID`, `Client Secret` and add `redirect URIs`

[image]
[image]

### Step 2 - Get code

```
https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={your client id}&scope=user-read-email&redirect_uri={your redirect URL, mine is http://localhost:3000}
```

Browser will show code in the address control, copy the `code` part.

[image]

### Step 3 - Get refresh

Get refresh code by curl from terminal

```
curl -d client_id={your client it} \
-d client_secret={your client secret} \
-d grant_type=authorization_code \
-d code={code from Step #2} \
-d redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000 \
https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token | jq
```

You can get the refresh token

```
{
  "access_token": "BQC...V-1"
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_token": "AQA...6twR
  "scope": "user-read-email"
}
```

Reference

[How to create a Spotify refresh token the easy way](https://benwiz.com/blog/create-spotify-refresh-token/)

Comment: this does not answer the question..

Comment: @Xiduzo, can you point which part is missing?

Comment: the whole point on how to do this with `expo-auth-session`, you are just explaining the oAuth flow of Spotify using curl instead of pointing out how to implement this potentially with the requested package