# Getting Object of type "None" is not subscriptable error while using Spotify API to retrieve track data

Tags: python, api, error-handling, spotify, spotipy

I am using Spotipy library to extract each song track information(e.g. album name, artist name) from Spotify playlist link. The code block below returns the output 'uris', but red wavy line on `sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_id=playlist_uri)['items']` indicates an error message <Object of type "None" is not subscriptable>.
I understand the error message itself, but cannot get a grip how this error message relates to my code. I tried to look at reportOptionalSubcript but doesn't seem like a solution for the root cause. Also tried printing output for each steps and see where the problem is stemming from but still need help.

Any advice would be appreciated!

My code:

```
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id = client_id, client_secret= client_secret)

sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager = client_credentials_manager)

# Playlist link
link = "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DX2Zjg8kBuEsQ"
# Get the URI of the playlist
playlist_uri = link.split("/")[-1]

# Get track information item for each track in the playlist
uris = [x for x in sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_id=playlist_uri)['items']]
```

Comment: What happens when `sp.playlist_tracks` fails? It appears to return `None`. I think you need to add error detection code - or catch this error as the error.

Comment: There's something wrong with your `client_id` and/or `client_secret`, because I tested your code with mine, and it worked.

Comment: I mean, check in your code if the `client_id` and `client_secret` are the same as in the dashboard of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Using Spotify API with `requests` in Python. It makes life easier.

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-playlist

```
  GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{playlist_id}
```

[image]

#### Python Code as `get-playlist.py` file.

```py
import requests

CLIENT_ID = '*************** your client ID ***************'
CLIENT_SECRET = '*********** your client secret ***********'

AUTH_URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
BASE_URL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/'
playlist_id = '37i9dQZF1DX2Zjg8kBuEsQ'

# POST
auth_response = requests.post(AUTH_URL, {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
})

# convert the response to JSON
auth_response_data = auth_response.json()

# save the access token
access_token = auth_response_data['access_token']

# print(access_token)

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {token}'.format(token=access_token)
}

# actual GET request with proper header
r = requests.get(BASE_URL + 'playlists/' + playlist_id, headers=headers)

r = r.json()

tracks = []
for item in r['tracks']['items']:
    tracks.append({
        'title' : item['track']['album']['name'],
        'artists' : item['track']['album']['artists'][0]['name'],
        'duration_ms' : item['track']['duration_ms'],
        'track URL' : item['track']['album']['external_urls']['spotify'],
    })

for track in tracks:
    print(track)
```

#### Result

```
$ python get-playlist.py
{'title': 'Special', 'artists': 'Lizzo', 'duration_ms': 191937, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/1KtDsGsSRGbnmH07v5hB1I'}
{'title': 'Doja', 'artists': 'Central Cee', 'duration_ms': 97392, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/6oECjagksATHu2UaclXrq1'}
{'title': 'B.O.T.A. (Baddest Of Them All)', 'artists': 'Eliza Rose', 'duration_ms': 226626, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/2lQgd3Svp1ZWAzZPLobAPK'}
{'title': 'Come Home The Kids Miss You', 'artists': 'Jack Harlow', 'duration_ms': 173947, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/2eE8BVirX9VF8Di9hD90iw'}
{'title': 'Hounds of Love (2018 Remaster)', 'artists': 'Kate Bush', 'duration_ms': 300840, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/3OYnManu1Nlxnw9OMng7BH'}
{'title': 'Afraid To Feel', 'artists': 'LF SYSTEM', 'duration_ms': 177524, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/528LrHfHcB7PMAvyp8Obhp'}
{'title': 'Calm Down (with Selena Gomez)', 'artists': 'Rema', 'duration_ms': 239317, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/2b2GHWESCWEuHiCZ2Skedp'}
{'title': 'Go (Remixes)', 'artists': 'Cat Burns', 'duration_ms': 192514, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/1kGbwOHke3PrRnZAmlkoOu'}
{'title': 'Finesse', 'artists': 'Pheelz', 'duration_ms': 155293, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/4QEC4uzBJJfLVv2bD337g1'}
{'title': "Takin' It Back", 'artists': 'Meghan Trainor', 'duration_ms': 134256, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/4LVa9bljQRvLYpWr8qyaXs'}
{'title': 'No Excuses', 'artists': 'Bru-C', 'duration_ms': 222453, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/1r6fzHMhZcd35ZkpKPRRWE'}
{'title': 'RENAISSANCE', 'artists': 'Beyonc▒', 'duration_ms': 225388, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/6FJxoadUE4JNVwWHghBwnb'}
{'title': 'Gemini Rights', 'artists': 'Steve Lacy', 'duration_ms': 232066, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/3Ks0eeH0GWpY4AU20D5HPD'}
{'title': 'Packs and Potions', 'artists': 'HAZEY', 'duration_ms': 160551, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/1VkcWtwCE0ktxyiZqjkCzu'}
{'title': 'messy in heaven', 'artists': 'venbee', 'duration_ms': 170437, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/0a9uNlopPXGg37OC20qDk6'}
{'title': 'KU LO SA - A COLORS SHOW', 'artists': 'Oxlade', 'duration_ms': 147580, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/36bNKiiUjxUCaAO7QtUVfi'}
{'title': 'BMW', 'artists': 'Bad Boy Chiller Crew', 'duration_ms': 213880, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/3U3FSuGS2CXktQD4fU78gM'}
{'title': 'Victoria▒s Secret', 'artists': 'Jax', 'duration_ms': 176124, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/47eeG5ewIbO53gXZOkvHhg'}
{'title': 'Euphoria (Original Score from the HBO Series)', 'artists': 'Labrinth', 'duration_ms': 91869, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/788r22Bhr3IHLTNPy8pZea'}
{'title': "Je M'appelle", 'artists': 'Benzz', 'duration_ms': 139574, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/6T6uWGOSAUhvoZfLlIyDuJ'}
{'title': 'I Ain▒t Worried (Music From The Motion Picture "Top Gun: Maverick")', 'artists': 'OneRepublic', 'duration_ms': 148485, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/04PEOM6kIEeq9lRp1asNP2'}
{'title': 'Boyfriend', 'artists': 'Dove Cameron', 'duration_ms': 153000, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/4jUfPmvZGiRRJwULbfk1dc'}
{'title': 'Glad U Came (feat. ZieZie)', 'artists': 'Liilz', 'duration_ms': 125142, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/52JvEc5EDwgA854xVckQL9'}
{'title': 'Jiggle Jiggle', 'artists': 'Duke & Jones', 'duration_ms': 97208, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/3WcZOQwZQ5gLyNrA0aXUeT'}
{'title': 'Fat Funny Friend', 'artists': 'Maddie Zahm', 'duration_ms': 199764, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/5NMKRqxbne8L5LerDnpGjk'}
{'title': 'Big City Life', 'artists': 'Luude', 'duration_ms': 146711, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/5Z9UyG6AYfNphE7UJGXifC'}
{'title': 'Sunroof', 'artists': 'Nicky Youre', 'duration_ms': 163025, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/0VaHnwzDug4AcDkejYDUl5'}
{'title': 'Friendly Sex', 'artists': 'Caity Baser', 'duration_ms': 159193, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/3KgVXRJUmbAS28XfHrJOs2'}
{'title': 'Safe Haven', 'artists': 'Ruth B.', 'duration_ms': 233720, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/6FgtuX3PtiB5civjHYhc52'}
{'title': 'channel ORANGE', 'artists': 'Frank Ocean', 'duration_ms': 234093, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/392p3shh2jkxUxY2VHvlH8'}
{'title': 'Miss You', 'artists': 'Oliver Tree', 'duration_ms': 206000, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/32G4vFNwLJQjpzkOoGEUUo'}
{'title': 'Super Freaky Girl', 'artists': 'Nicki Minaj', 'duration_ms': 170977, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/0h5MuD9O9o1VoN07mQmwMQ'}
{'title': 'BILLIE EILISH.', 'artists': 'Armani White', 'duration_ms': 99282, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/4MajX5vPeY4cX5pv6rf0sA'}
{'title': '10 Things I Hate About You', 'artists': 'Leah Kate', 'duration_ms': 157138, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/26hYEKjKZU1sTC4mUPpVI6'}
{'title': 'LA Leakers Freestyle', 'artists': 'Central Cee', 'duration_ms': 178000, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/5BdTpc5WQMyt0qBuJ5mDCH'}
{'title': 'Betty (Get Money)', 'artists': 'Yung Gravy', 'duration_ms': 146470, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/3FEQZNn34v3EdxrVKi9pZF'}
{'title': 'Rainfall (Praise You)', 'artists': 'Tom Santa', 'duration_ms': 166569, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/4VanY5i4E59Mhz52qznJ95'}
{'title': 'froge.mp3', 'artists': 'piri', 'duration_ms': 135386, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/4AueWk2dGXqbMFx7ogEAs7'}
{'title': 'IFTK', 'artists': 'Tion Wayne', 'duration_ms': 190684, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/6IZ5CNSuwvcAnmnxfmVvl5'}
{'title': 'Ivory', 'artists': 'Omar Apollo', 'duration_ms': 216680, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/5z7TD11Qh81Gbf52hd5zAv'}
{'title': 'Drunk', 'artists': 'Thundercat', 'duration_ms': 188453, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/7vHBQDqwzB7uDvoE5bncMM'}
{'title': 'Special', 'artists': 'Lizzo', 'duration_ms': 187107, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/1NgFBv1PxMG1zhFDW1OrRr'}
{'title': "Harry's House", 'artists': 'Harry Styles', 'duration_ms': 193813, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/5r36AJ6VOJtp00oxSkBZ5h'}
{'title': 'reputation', 'artists': 'Taylor Swift', 'duration_ms': 236413, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/6DEjYFkNZh67HP7R9PSZvv'}
{'title': 'SPACE MAN', 'artists': 'Sam Ryder', 'duration_ms': 217320, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/7uJgYMaJcQ25PhywdJfrJF'}
{'title': 'Vegas (From the Original Motion Picture Soundtrack ELVIS)', 'artists': 'Doja Cat', 'duration_ms': 182906, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/2Q5DPv9uliinOBSdNooIe3'}
{'title': 'Ronaldo (SEWY)', 'artists': 'IShowSpeed', 'duration_ms': 102019, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/1HGtrBJ0dCm0FmgLxBBo8P'}
{'title': "Tell Me It's Real (Expanded Edition)", 'artists': 'Seafret', 'duration_ms': 229173, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/4m8XN9CKqve1ExYBnNu5kt'}
{'title': 'low down', 'artists': 'venbee', 'duration_ms': 182923, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/48KWh33PB86WJeyFhQOkVl'}
{'title': 'Chit Chat', 'artists': 'Beach Weather', 'duration_ms': 196784, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/1xz1n7gyY02veDxH50SQHQ'}
{'title': 'Starboy', 'artists': 'The Weeknd', 'duration_ms': 260253, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/2ODvWsOgouMbaA5xf0RkJe'}
{'title': 'Next Up - S4-E2', 'artists': 'Mixtape Madness', 'duration_ms': 120839, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/0j070iW9OV0gL2IbSWIHcE'}
{'title': 'RENAISSANCE', 'artists': 'Beyonc▒', 'duration_ms': 278281, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/6FJxoadUE4JNVwWHghBwnb'}
{'title': 'Pretty One', 'artists': 'Koomz', 'duration_ms': 182169, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/1xn5iNKJUkVV5qC6y6GEXS'}
{'title': "It's Not Me, It's You", 'artists': 'Lily Allen', 'duration_ms': 219893, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/39zjAZD6nlscx5DafH8GI8'}
{'title': 'Glimpse of Us', 'artists': 'Joji', 'duration_ms': 233456, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/6ZZvx0aefZV3LKa053fn71'}
{'title': 'Down Under (feat. Colin Hay)', 'artists': 'Luude', 'duration_ms': 158774, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/64xmSwJJbFQMf63AFYZXpW'}
{'title': 'Anthology', 'artists': 'Musical Youth', 'duration_ms': 205426, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/7EaFCudrleGdoYFl2srjhi'}
{'title': 'Wet Dream', 'artists': 'Wet Leg', 'duration_ms': 140083, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/2EVCxBosAlVsC0d7DAJXCA'}
{'title': 'Turn On The Lights again.. (feat. Future)', 'artists': 'Fred again..', 'duration_ms': 267946, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/2jiMeC1iUWVYmvXSIiO8ks'}
{'title': 'Night Away (Dance) (feat. Tion Wayne)', 'artists': 'A1 x J1', 'duration_ms': 175774, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/6WQPgcOtZCoXGBZQOxDJQ0'}
{'title': 'Favourite Worst Nightmare (Standard Version)', 'artists': 'Arctic Monkeys', 'duration_ms': 253586, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/6rsQnwaoJHxXJRCDBPkBRw'}
{'title': 'Birthday Cake', 'artists': 'Dylan Conrique', 'duration_ms': 205280, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/6Z2I7RVroN2B24d7mms0tT'}
{'title': 'Offering', 'artists': 'Cults', 'duration_ms': 212736, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/1FUaSRyu5LIj1QpMXRncxt'}
{'title': 'Playboy', 'artists': 'Fireboy DML', 'duration_ms': 187111, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/1pUJnA3OSbvVr5afqxNARZ'}
{'title': 'SNAP', 'artists': 'Rosa Linn', 'duration_ms': 179551, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/4fb1QzgTJpTk9TBjFzjmlR'}
{'title': 'Until I Found You', 'artists': 'Stephen Sanchez', 'duration_ms': 177720, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/18CtLoAMTr7F8ngtuM6D8i'}
{'title': 'abcdefu', 'artists': 'GAYLE', 'duration_ms': 168601, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/6tUQPKlpR4x1gjrXTtOImI'}
{'title': 'Balling (feat. Songer, Mr Traumatik, Devilman & OneDa) [Edit]', 'artists': 'Vibe Chemistry', 'duration_ms': 266206, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/775Vio9oXjiTAbh7Ad15ay'}
{'title': 'Shen Yeng Anthem', 'artists': 'Shenseea', 'duration_ms': 141226, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/5ITcrOlnxhUg2uvlGNPJhT'}
{'title': 'Deep Down (feat. Never Dull)', 'artists': 'Alok', 'duration_ms': 165752, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/3KpxpdySrMR2S7noneu1bI'}
{'title': 'Beautiful Lies', 'artists': 'Birdy', 'duration_ms': 208395, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/5wNnopxjgSKVvHTIcBpV8Q'}
{'title': 'Ferrari', 'artists': 'James Hype', 'duration_ms': 186661, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/6moZ4sNThthUAwCklyuPY8'}
{'title': 'Mockingbird (Remix)', 'artists': 'E1 (3x3)', 'duration_ms': 192362, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/7BXb7pTQSCicF0duwhWd9E'}
{'title': 'Flowers', 'artists': 'Lauren Spencer Smith', 'duration_ms': 157373, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/03sQVTmOjeFVi8GsSaJSNV'}
{'title': "Harry's House", 'artists': 'Harry Styles', 'duration_ms': 245964, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/5r36AJ6VOJtp00oxSkBZ5h'}
{'title': 'Temptation (feat. Poppy Baskcomb)', 'artists': 'Jess Bays', 'duration_ms': 172197, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/30K7gYPhkqCeQJ25C0GvXE'}
{'title': 'Voulez-Vous', 'artists': 'ABBA', 'duration_ms': 260893, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/7iLuHJkrb9KHPkMgddYigh'}
{'title': 'Stan Smith', 'artists': 'Alcemist', 'duration_ms': 235000, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/2s7f4Qihh5MV7D6lKLPBjB'}
{'title': 'Poland', 'artists': 'Lil Yachty', 'duration_ms': 83200, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/5LZiWbqOpj6g8uxSHch12S'}
{'title': 'Diplo', 'artists': 'Diplo', 'duration_ms': 199090, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/5pdR4YX2zWMXotdF034UYY'}
{'title': 'Visions', 'artists': 'Grimes', 'duration_ms': 255320, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/3HED2IUaNSnbOe88a7ZdwM'}
{'title': 'SUPERMODEL', 'artists': 'M▒neskin', 'duration_ms': 148064, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/5jhbLeXH1a3SRSOg84GSUn'}
{'title': 'Satin Panthers', 'artists': 'Hudson Mohawke', 'duration_ms': 171720, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/0d99LxnQpiPLgSGDRuU9HT'}
{'title': 'Hold This', 'artists': 'HStikkytokky', 'duration_ms': 145920, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/242dSF54Qx1DKFwmHLGUGA'}
{'title': 'Oslo', 'artists': 'Lil Macks', 'duration_ms': 154906, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/03ti301zMUad9uUP7CGgF1'}
{'title': 'MEAN!', 'artists': 'Madeline The Person', 'duration_ms': 143960, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/1JX43p0bIGOMiHjdgoyAQD'}
{'title': 'Being Funny In A Foreign Language', 'artists': 'The 1975', 'duration_ms': 326490, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/6dVCpQ7oGJD1oYs2fv1t5M'}
{'title': 'IGOR', 'artists': 'Tyler, The Creator', 'duration_ms': 195320, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/5zi7WsKlIiUXv09tbGLKsE'}
{'title': 'Eye Tell (!)', 'artists': 'Jim Legxacy', 'duration_ms': 130692, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/1piNdNQfDq2mW2BiHC30by'}
{'title': 'SloMo', 'artists': 'Chanel', 'duration_ms': 176285, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/0UMDRKVU0rz2nALo2bms9d'}
{'title': 'Just Wanna Rock', 'artists': 'Lil Uzi Vert', 'duration_ms': 123890, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/2FD6g8bXEn2uQMYbeqqoCg'}
{'title': 'Essex Girls (feat. Jaykae, Silky & Janice Robinson)', 'artists': 'Rude Kid', 'duration_ms': 160000, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/1XTzHBeO7yYUnkkYN6i0V1'}
{'title': 'Mr Worldwide', 'artists': 'Pete & Bas', 'duration_ms': 181254, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/0UGJ7jvU1Dn14J7BCMCP1f'}
{'title': 'Forbidden Feelingz', 'artists': 'Nia Archives', 'duration_ms': 166356, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/5OoEG2axfMGY44nUNMayoW'}
{'title': 'tonight belongs to you', 'artists': 'Bissett', 'duration_ms': 147075, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/5oEWotsYKfSnkN6Hp11yMS'}
{'title': 'FOUND LOVE (feat. Carrie Baxter)', 'artists': 'NOTION', 'duration_ms': 136615, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/7ut4PfRhGtazFoK7UOMxbs'}
{'title': 'DJ Party (Monster)', 'artists': 'wewantwraiths', 'duration_ms': 194032, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/2UVZtK15LKQBJkl54Z8wvg'}
{'title': 'Public Displays Of Affection: The Album', 'artists': 'Muni Long', 'duration_ms': 204316, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/7fe4Mem3wWgY6zkTFuKUI9'}
{'title': 'I Love You.', 'artists': 'The Neighbourhood', 'duration_ms': 240400, 'track URL': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/4xkM0BwLM9H2IUcbYzpcBI'}
```

#### How to file a title, artist, duration and track URL

Using Postman - it is cool tool for REST API debugging.

#1 Get Access Token - POST request

```
POST https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

In Body, select `x-www-form-urlencoded`
and KEY with VALUE with those value.

```
grant_type client_credentials
```

[image]

In Tests, copy/paste it.
It will assign varaible into `access-token`

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("access-token", jsonData.access_token);
console.log(jsonData.access_token);
```

[image]

In Authorization, Select `Basic Auth` type and copy paste your credential.

```
CLIENT_ID -> Username
CLIENT_SECRET -> Password
```

Finally, press `Send` Button

[image]

#2 Get Access Playlist - GET request

```
GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/37i9dQZF1DX2Zjg8kBuEsQ
```

In Authorization, select `Bearer Token` and enter `{{access-token}}` in Token input.

Press `Send` button, you can get the JSON response.

[image]

#3 Access data
by dictionary access variable['key'] (if start `{` )OR
by list access variable[index] (if start `[` )

r['tracks']['items'] - access  `items`

[image]
child start with `[`
It will access list - we are for loop - `item`
item started `{` - dictionary
all of child(tract)/grand child(album)/grand grand child(artists) are dictionary and it started `{` it is list so [0] - first item of list then back to final `name` as dictionary.
So it can access by this.

```
'artists' : item['track']['album']['artists'][0]['name']
```

Other properties same idea.
I hope to you can leverage Postman for debugging.

Comment: Sejung is already using SpotiPy. Why is your solution easier than using that Python module?

Comment: And as I said in a comment under the question, the code isn't the problem, but the copied client_id and/or client_secret.

Comment: Haha, It is my option, low level is easy to handle then high level with SDK. I have no experience SDK at all.

Comment: Is It  Postman part or Python code for ID/Secret?

Comment: @Ximzend, I made how copy from id/Secret in here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74651517/expo-auth-session-spotify-get-refresh-token/74655243#74655243